Selenium does not work inside the docker container
I have written a python script which uses selenium and work as I wanted but when I try to work it on docker container it gives me this error:
ERROR - An error occurred during the main task: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=xxxxx): Read timed out. (read timeout=120)
Piece of code that gives me exception
import logging
import signal
import smtplib
import time
import base64
import pytesseract
import sys
import json
import os
from seleniumbase import SB
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageFilter
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import chromedriver_autoinstaller


chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()  # Check if the current version of chromedriver exists


def main_task(config):
    global sb_instance
    try: 
        with SB(uc=True, headless2=True, undetectable=True, use_auto_ext=False) as sb:
        # Main logic but can't reach here
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("An error occurred during the main task: %s", str(e))
        return -1

HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=xxxxxx) Read timed out. (read timeout=120)

Dockerfile
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.9-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    wget \
    gnupg \
    tesseract-ocr \
    libglib2.0-0 \
    libnss3 \
    libgconf-2-4 \
    libxss1 \
    fonts-liberation \
    libappindicator3-1 \
    xdg-utils \
    unzip \
    net-tools \
    iputils-ping \
    dbus \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor > /usr/share/keyrings/google-chrome-keyring.gpg && \
    echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/google-chrome-keyring.gpg] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

ENV DISPLAY=:99
ENV PATH="/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seleniumbase/drivers/:${PATH}"

CMD ["python", "sel.py"]


Docker command
    docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -it --name aperol-spritz --cpus="8" --shm-size=4g -v $PWD:/app:rw -w /app $BASE_IMAGE bash -c "pip install -r /app/requirements.txt && python /app/sel.py"


Docker inspect
{
    "Id": "314969c0f7695f87e7af8a22bad419d60b7221ad36783b27ae8b4a1d60922904",
    "Created": "2024-12-06T04:29:34.960458338Z",
    "Path": "bash",
    "Args": [
        "-c",
        "pip install -r /app/requirements.txt && python /app/sel.py"
    ],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 25079,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2024-12-06T04:29:35.039250047Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:410d4b429be3a8044d27d231f92089700c1da0cf124cfcb41e42c8f153043fde",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/314969c0f7695f87e7af8a22bad419d60b7221ad36783b27ae8b4a1d60922904/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/314969c0f7695f87e7af8a22bad419d60b7221ad36783b27ae8b4a1d60922904/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/314969c0f7695f87e7af8a22bad419d60b7221ad36783b27ae8b4a1d60922904/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/314969c0f7695f87e7af8a22bad419d60b7221ad36783b27ae8b4a1d60922904/314969c0f7695f87e7af8a22bad419d60b7221ad36783b27ae8b4a1d60922904-json.log",
    "Name": "/aperol-spritz",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "overlay2",
    "Platform": "linux",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": [
        "7407cea0c7ac7d2295fcf51f99ee9992834b141c56ad74e01c45d2ee0295642d"
    ],
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "/Users/frozen/Documents/ClionProjects/sel:/app:rw"
        ],
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "bridge",
        "PortBindings": {
            "8080/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ]
        },
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "AutoRemove": false,
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "ConsoleSize": [
            41,
            187
        ],
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "CgroupnsMode": "private",
        "Dns": [],
        "DnsOptions": [],
        "DnsSearch": [],
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "private",
        "Cgroup": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 4294967296,
        "Runtime": "runc",
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "NanoCpus": 8000000000,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": [],
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": [],
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": [],
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": [],
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": [],
        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
        "DeviceRequests": null,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "OomKillDisable": null,
        "PidsLimit": null,
        "Ulimits": [],
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
        "MaskedPaths": [
            "/proc/asound",
            "/proc/acpi",
            "/proc/kcore",
            "/proc/keys",
            "/proc/latency_stats",
            "/proc/timer_list",
            "/proc/timer_stats",
            "/proc/sched_debug",
            "/proc/scsi",
            "/sys/firmware",
            "/sys/devices/virtual/powercap"
        ],
        "ReadonlyPaths": [
            "/proc/bus",
            "/proc/fs",
            "/proc/irq",
            "/proc/sys",
            "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
        ]
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6b6ebea6bd46f0ba9dd7c7a81b427188e7dc380a2d0aa06ae8807873999639e5-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/mlje1ari6gak9pna09zfrih25/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/vk4w9hg69j4s3nusauk7ns4ld/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f737d0bea1171662c6997bfc3df7cf033162f21c937babffc4261523b328f191/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/14eff14f8b6ee79e6ce8828fc642ef447784d607749d784a0dd9fe44ffa6cbc7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b2fed1798c5a3965b6b7de7e907474a9fa6c1f207b8ea1212e2b629cdf2f1699/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5d4f24be554957235b3ec5272c7d0d3e7f1648a8780dfb1ada1f8ddf6a3c8048/diff",
            "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6b6ebea6bd46f0ba9dd7c7a81b427188e7dc380a2d0aa06ae8807873999639e5/merged",
            "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6b6ebea6bd46f0ba9dd7c7a81b427188e7dc380a2d0aa06ae8807873999639e5/diff",
            "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6b6ebea6bd46f0ba9dd7c7a81b427188e7dc380a2d0aa06ae8807873999639e5/work"
        },
        "Name": "overlay2"
    },
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/Users/frozen/Documents/ClionProjects/sel",
            "Destination": "/app",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
    ],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "314969c0f769",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "8080/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": true,
        "OpenStdin": true,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seleniumbase/drivers/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "LANG=C.UTF-8",
            "GPG_KEY=E3FF2839C048B25C084DEBE9B26995E310250568",
            "PYTHON_VERSION=3.9.21",
            "PYTHON_SHA256=3126f59592c9b0d798584755f2bf7b081fa1ca35ce7a6fea980108d752a05bb1",
            "DISPLAY=:99"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "bash",
            "-c",
            "pip install -r /app/requirements.txt && python /app/sel.py"
        ],
        "Image": "sel-checker",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "/app",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {}
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "02fdbb1788b199a15a9aa1f539396287ccf8677fb63496172e463240cfdf6b40",
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/02fdbb1788b1",
        "Ports": {
            "8080/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ]
        },
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "925a9ebbc452e3ddf7430e796c8172e1895ae4ad6858b60cdbfefc40e27da0db",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": null,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "DriverOpts": null,
                "NetworkID": "584122c832b4242992e1ce649fccfee9bef27b81bc1f0d8b4e2a233729494033",
                "EndpointID": "925a9ebbc452e3ddf7430e796c8172e1895ae4ad6858b60cdbfefc40e27da0db",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "DNSNames": null
            }
        }
    }
}

What I tried:

--network host flag for my container
Tuned the memory and cpu of the container
Rebuilding/restarting docker image and container


I solved it with using chromium instead of chrome driver
